# How do I make a new grid?

Tags: java, jpanel, grid-layout

I'm putting a bunch of buttons into GridLayout. If I want the user to be able to change the grid size during run time, how do I generate a new grid? I tried resetting the row/cols and re-adding the buttons, but nothing changes.

Late edit of cope snippet for resizing the grid:

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(10, 10);;

void makeGrid(int newSize) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= gridSize; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j <= gridSize; j++) {
          layout.removeLayoutComponent(grid[i][j]);
       }
    }

    gridSize = newSize;
    layout = new GridLayout(gridSize, gridSize);
    panel.setLayout(layout);

    for(int i = 0; i <= gridSize; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j <= gridSize; j++) {
          panel.add(grid[i][j]);
       }
    }
    pack();
}
```

Comment: What is your GUI? What does GridLayout belong to?

Comment: It's just a 2D array of JButtons. The GridLayout belongs to a JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

try defining a separate method for displaying the buttons like,

```
// pane is your JPanel object
public void displayButtons(){
   pane.add(btn1);
   pane.add(btn2);
   pane.add(btn3);
   pane.add(btn4);
   pane.add(btn5);
   pane.add(btn6);
   pack(); // <- make sure you include this code
}
```

Then from your class listener, set a new layout then call displayButtons() method.

```
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
displayButtons();
```

Comment: Thanks, pack() is doing the trick as far as updating the GUI goes--this just adds more buttons to the ones that already existed, though, unless I'm missing something. Calling removeLayoutComponent() doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Maybe I can help you better if you show me a snippet of your code and we'll see if you're missing something...